# jQuery UI Explode Effect Not Working on Other Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI's explode effect on some text. Although the code works on my index page, the explode effect stops working after being redirected to another page (by using `window.location.replace()`). Instead, the text just disappears without any effects.

Here's the Javascript code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".header-primary").hide("explode", {pieces: 32}, 2000);
}, 3000);
```

The code is placed into a JavaScript file that all of the pages have inside the head. The head is completely the same for all pages. In addition, all of the pages share the same piece of code that I want to explode:

```
<h1 class="header-primary">
    <em>Header</em>
    <h1 class="header-primary-subheader">Subheader</h1>
</h1>
```

Comment: Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to reproduce issue?

Comment: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FcD1lCudkiLcM3gybO2g) it is. Although it works perfectly here, it seems to fail when I'm working on it. I'm using Cloud9, could that affect anything?

Comment: Have not tried Cloud9. Have you reviewed `console` at plnkr `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`? `<script>` which loads bootstrap is expecting jQuery to be defined, though is placed before <script>`  which loads jQuery at `html`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've decided to gone with the puff effect instead, and it works flawlessly.